# Como contar as colunas de uma <td> mostrando o tatal no final

Tags: typescript, angular

Estou fazendo uma lista de chamadas e preciso contar quantas faltas presenças e justificativa cada aluno tem, mas não estou conseguindo. Alguém poderia dar um luz.

Estou perdido nessa parte.

```
    <!-- PRECISO SOMAR AS PRESENÇAS -->
    <td style="text-align: center">{{totalPresente}}</td> 
    <!-- PRECISO SOMAR AS FALTAS -->
    <td style="text-align: center">00</td>
```

Segue meu código

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bzbaez)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código está um pouco complicado de se entender, mas creio que irá ajudar.

Crie um método para retornar a quantidade de presenças e faltas de cada aluno, percorra o objeto `alunos` utilizando o método `forEach`, a cada loop faça um filtro no objeto `presencas` utilizando o método `filter`, ele retornar um novo array com os objetos que passaram no teste, depois recupere o número de elementos desse array.

```
calcularPresencas () {
  this.alunos.forEach((aluno, index) => {
    // Filtra por "cd_aluno" e pela "situacao" para presença
    this.alunos[index].totalPresente = this.presencas.filter(p => p.cd_aluno === aluno.cd_aluno && p.situacao === 'p').length;
    // Filtra por "cd_aluno" e pela "situacao" para falta
    this.alunos[index].totalFalta = this.presencas.filter(p => p.cd_aluno === aluno.cd_aluno && p.situacao === 'f').length;
  });
}
```

Execute ele no método `ngOnInit()` após `this.getAlunos();`

```
...
this.calcularPresencas();
```

No do método `salvar(aluno, dia, situacao)` faça um filtro no objeto `presencas` por `cd_aluno` e `nu_dia`, caso o número de elementos retornado seja maior que **0** ele atualiza a situação existente, caso contrário irá adicionar o objeto `form` no objeto `presencas`. Depois chame o método `calcularPresencas` para atualizar os dados:

```
// Filtra por "cd_aluno" e "nu_dia"
let al = this.presencas.filter(p => p.cd_aluno == aluno.cd_aluno && p.nu_dia === dia);
//  Verifica se o número de elementos retornado é maior que "0"
(al.length > 0) ? al[0].situacao = situacao : this.presencas.push(form);
// Executa o método para atualizar os dados
this.calcularPresencas();
```

O template:

```
<!-- PRECISO SOMAR AS FALTAS -->
<td style="text-align: center">{{aluno.totalFalta}}</td>
<!-- PRECISO SOMAR AS PRESENÇAS -->
<td style="text-align: center">{{aluno.totalPresente}}</td>
```

Perceba que eu alterei a ordem, pois estava errado.

> Podes ver funcionando em [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-26rugu).

Comment: wmsouza Muito obrigado